# Error message spacing not working in TextInputLayout Outlined style

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to implement a form using MaterialComponents TextInputLayout. According to the [docs](https://material.io/components/text-fields#specs), it should have a space for error message. I've enabled error message in my layout xml and it also shows in the Android Studio layout preview but is not working in the application.

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Preview:

[image]

What is actually happening:

[image]

Comment: What version of Material Design Components are you using?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat    'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

Comment: Try using 1.2.0-alpha06. There are some fixes to error behaviours in this version. It works fine for me with 1.1.0.

Comment: It is just the default behavior of the widget. You try setting helper text if you want that preview space always occupied and visible.

Comment: I found a solution guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling errorMessage right after disabling it when the input is valid.

```
    else {  // Condition finally met when error is valid
        signinEmailLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        signinEmailLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
    }
```

As suggested in comments by @MRamzan , it seems this is the default behaviour. Anyway, in my activity class, I was setting errorEnabled to false which caused the layout to remove the space designated for error message when the input was valid. As soon as the input was invalid again, the error message got added, as I was enabling it again, and hence the unstable UX was there.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `app:errorEnabled="true"` will modify the layout to leave space for the error text to appear. The problem is you're setting `errorEnabled=false` to hide the error which removes the space for the error text.

Instead always keep `errorEnabled=true` and use `TextInputLayout#error` to show and hide the error.

```kotlin
// Shows error text and UI
nameInputLayout.error = getString(R.string.error)

// Hides error text and UI
nameInputLayout.error = null
```

See https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields under "Adding errors to a text field"